# ¿Cómo ejecutar una vista al clicar un botón en un template de django?

Tags: html, python, django, template, django-views

Estoy intentando hacer un proyecto muy simple de Django, en el cual mi objetivo es que al pinchar en un botón que tengo en un formulario de Django, dependiendo de que radio button esté pinchado, te ponga un numero mas largo o mas corto. El problema que tengo es que no se como llamar a la vista que he creado, que simplemente pasa como contexto el numero que crea, al html. Así es como tengo mis archivos de configuración

"index.html"

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Prueba</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'generate_random' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% if number %}
            <p>El número:  {{ number }}</p>
        {% endif %}
      {{ form }}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse, redirect
from .forms import SelectForm
import random
import string


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, "principal/index.html")

def generate_random(request):
    context = {}
    number = 20

    if request.method == 'POST': # 1
        form = SelectForm(request.POST) # 2
        if form.is_valid(): # 3
            choice = form.cleaned_data['select_choice'] # 4 
            if choice == 'short': # 5
                number = 1
            elif choice == 'normal':
                number = 2
            else:
                number = 3

            context.update({'number': number}) # 6
    else:
        context.update({'form': SelectForm()}) # 7

    return render(request, "principal/index.html", context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path
from principal import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
    path('',views.generate_random, name='generate_random'),
]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import models

SELECT_CHOICES = (
  ('short', 'Short'),
  ('normal', 'Normal'),
  ('long', 'Long'),
)

class SelectForm(forms.Form):
    select_choice = models.ChoiceField(choices=SELECT_CHOICES)
```

mi models.py esta vacío, pero creo que no lo necesito, ¿no?
Acabo de actualizar el código con la respuesta de abajo, pero sigo teniendo el problema

Answer (score 0):

Te será mucho más fácil resolver este problema si haces uso de los formularios en Django. Puedes ver aquí cómo funcionan los [Django Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/).

Como verás en esa documentación, lo que necesitas se puede conseguir con una sola vista.

#### forms.py

```
from django import forms

SELECT_CHOICES = (
  ('short', 'Short'),
  ('normal', 'Normal'),
  ('long', 'Long'),
)

class SelectForm(forms.Form):
    select_choice = models.ChoiceField(choices=SELECT_CHOICES)
```

Como ves aquí, lo que he hecho es generar un formulario en el que podrás elegir entre tres opciones de números aleatorios.

Con esto ya tienes elaborado tu formulario que puedes meter en el `<body>` de tu `template`.

#### template (index.html, por ejemplo)

```
{% if number %}
<p>El número:  {{ number }}</p>
{% endif %}

<form method="POST" action="{% url 'generate_random' %}">
  {{ form }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"
</form>
```

Aquí lo único que hacemos es mostrar el número, si lo hay, y el formulario.

Vista, como te decía, sólo te hace falta una, que podría ser algo así:

#### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import SelectForm

def generate_random(request):
    context = {}

    if request.method == 'POST': # 1
        form = SelectForm(request.POST) # 2
        if form.is_valid(): # 3
            choice = form.cleaned_data['select_choice'] # 4 
            if choice == 'short': # 5
                number = ...
            elif choice == 'normal':
                ...
            else:
                ...

            context.update({'number': number}) # 6
    else:
        context.update({'form': SelectForm()}) # 7

    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

Si vas de arriba hacia abajo, lo que hacemos aquí es:

1. Comprobar si hemos llegado a esta vista haciendo post al formulario o no.
2. En el caso de que sí, recuperamos el formulario con los parámetros que le hayamos metido al hacer post.
3. Comprobamos que el formulario es válido.
4. Si lo es, sacamos la elección del tipo de número y lo ponemos en la variable `choice`.
5. En función de la variable `choice` generamos el número correspondiente.
6. Actualizamos el contexto, que es lo que mandaremos luego al template.
7. En caso de que hayamos llegado a la vista haciendo un get, le metemos el formulario al contexto y a tomar vientos.

Por último, renderizamos la template con el contexto actualizado y a volar.

Te pongo también un ejemplo de URLs, porque puede ser que te esté dando problemas también:

#### urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path
from principal import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.generate_random, name='generate_random'),
]
```

Ten en cuenta que los `paths` deben ser diferentes para diferentes vistas, si no Django no va a saber dónde tiene que meterse. Si quisieras meter una nueva ruta para una página previa (que no te  hace falta en este caso) tendrías que hacer algo así:

#### urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path
from principal import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name='index'),
    path('random/',views.generate_random, name='generate_random'),
]
```

Comment: Buenas! Me ha sido de gran utilidad tus pasos. De hecho, he aprendido varias cosas que no entendía. Estoy usando el forms.py tal y como me has dicho, y he creado la vista, pero tengo el problema, de que, aunque envia el dato pulsado así -> ""GET /prueba/?select_choice=short HTTP/1.1" 200", pero luego no me muestra nada. Tengo tambien el "if" dentro del form tal y como has puesto. He estado poniendo prints en la view, y por lo que veo, ni siquiera entra aqui -> "request.method == 'POST':". ¿Se te ocurre porque puede ser? Si es necesario, te envío como tengo lo demás

Comment: Culpa mía, amigo. En el template tienes que poner `method="POST"` en lugar de `method="GET"` en el `form`. Actualizo la respuesta para que esté correcto.

Comment: Acabo de actualizar el codigo de la pregunta inicial con lo que tengo actualmente por si podrias echarle un vistazo. Te agradezco enormemente tu respuesta, puesto que me ha guiado en el problema indicado. Aun así, no consigo llegar a ello.  Un fuerte saludo.

Comment: No sé muy bien el problema que tienes ahora con lo que has puesto. Pero te transcribo también el `urls.py` porque puede ser que por aquí también tengas problemas. Te recomiendo también que hagas el [tutorial de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/) completo (se tarda muy poquito) y te va a venir muy bien.